# What is the point of using the gloves that leave the knuckles exposed that the Florida State Boxing Commission is imposing for bare-knuckle boxing?

Tags: boxing

I read on https://twitter.com/adamlebarr/status/1131373692322234369, regarding the Bare Knuckle Fighting Championship (BKFC) 6 event on 2019-06-22:

[image]

What is the point of using the gloves that leave the knuckles exposed that the Florida State Boxing Commission is imposing for bare-knuckle boxing?

Comment: You do understand the point of calling it ***bare-knuckle***, right?

Comment: @Nij yes but why use gloves?

Comment: Because the law requires it, as your own snapshot says.

Comment: @Nij ok but what's the rationale behind it? I'm assuming they don't make laws for the sake of it.

Comment: This is the Florida State **Boxing** Commission under discussion. Clearly someone defined what boxing is and requires in order to be considered legitimate, and that includes gloves.

Comment: @Nij what difference does it make to wear gloves?

Comment: Ask the person who wrote the law. It mattered enough to them to include it.

Comment: @Nij probably I'm guessing they might have publicly shared the reason, or that the usefulness of wearing such gloves can be fathomed without asking them.